# Angular when i Creating new Component and call on string variable then show this type of error

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EAro.png)
Error occurs in the template of component BBComponent.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, to improve your question.

Comment: Even though you've provided no info to help with this I'm going to guess it's because you've forgotten to save your bb.component.ts file, so `name` hasn't ben declared yet.

Comment: Have u saved the file ? Have u closed the P tag ?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As others have suggested, please improve your question to better state the issue. Provide code samples of both the .ts and .html files so others can identify the issue. From the looks of your screenshot, I would say Alex's suggestion is your solution.